# click event not triggered on bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to catch the click event when `save changes` is pushed.

For some reason i can't catch the click event.

Why?

```
<script>
            $('#inviteRequest').click(function(){
//                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(1);
                $('#myModalInviteDestination').modal('hide');
            });

        </script>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalInviteDestination" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Enter your friends email address</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="68" name="invites"></textarea>
                        <div>use ; as delimiter</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inviteRequest">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to wrap this in a document.ready:

```
$(function() {
    $('#inviteRequest').click(function(){
        console.log(1);
        $('#myModalInviteDestination').modal('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your element `#inviteRequest` does not exist at the time you try to add an event handler to it. You need to wait for the page to load first. My code is the equivalent to [$(document).ready();](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 1):

Use "live" which will bind the element when element will create

```
$('#inviteRequest').live('click',function(){
console.log(1);
$('#myModalInviteDestination').modal('hide');});
```